# Mock a static method with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want to mock a static method in Mockito.

As far as I know this is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482315/why-does-mockito-not-mock-static-methods), how can I get around the problem?
powermock is not an option.

I want that my authentication variable won't be null.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

I read an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139841/how-to-mock-static-methods-with-mockito) but I don't know how to put this answer to code.
Can someone give a solution?

Comment: Inject the SecurityContext instead of looking it up using SecurityContextHolder.getContext(). If you posted more code, we could me more helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you pointed out, it is not possible to mock static methods with Mockito and since you do not wanna use Powermock or other tools, you can try something as follows in your tests.

1. Create test authentication object

   `Authentication auth = new ... // create instance based on your needs and with required attributes or just mock it if you do not care`
2. Mock security context

   `SecurityContext context = mock(SecurityContext.class);`
3. Ensure your mock returns the respective authentication

   `when(context.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(auth);`
4. Set security context into holder

   `SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);`

Now every call to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` should return authentication object created in step 1.

Comment: Even though this answer is a couple of years old now, it did help me out in a similar situation. Thanks!